# GoLang Validator Non-Required Fields Returns Error

Tags: validation, go

I'm using [GoLang Validator](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v10) on a struct to validate its fields. Even though I don't add `required` tag, it still behaves as if it is required.

```golang
type Order struct {
    // ... other fields
    UserID string `json:"userId" validate:"uuid4"`
    // ... other fields
}

if err = validator.New().Struct(i); err != nil {
    return err
}
```

Output: `User ID: unknown error`

It is not required hence the value is zero-value but it still returns an error. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

You should add the [`omitempty`](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v10#hdr-Omit_Empty) validator to allow empty values. [Try out the code below on Go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/S-bhF7GJAB-).

```
    type Order struct {
        // ... other fields
        UserID string `json:"omitempty,userId" validate:"omitempty,uuid4"`
        // ... other fields
    }

    if err := validator.New().Struct(Order{}); err != nil {
        return err
    }
```

Note that to marshal the struct to JSON you also need to set the `omitempty` validator if you want to allow empty values...